# Better AI for Tic & Toe

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, artificial-intelligence

I am creating a Tic & Toe game, which contains a PC player. It is a 3 x 3 game board, which then contains 9  buttons. Once the human player click on a button (which means, mark 'x'), the PC player automatically select the next one.  Please have a look at the following **piece** of code, which I developed for the PC player for selecting suitable button to mark 'o'.

```
if(buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[2].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[3].setText("O");
            buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
        } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[6].setText("O");
            buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
        } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
            buttons[9].setText("O");
            buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
        }
```

I am not happy with this. This is just a small piece, the If else is very long, checking each button one by one. I can't call it AI. If I make the grid 4 x 4, that means I need to edit the whole if else!

Is there any better way of selecting the PC player's 'o' mark button? Please help!

**UPDATE**

I am not seeking for the set of winning states. I am seeking for an algorithm or something where I can eliminate the if else.

Comment: You do realize tic-tac-toe is easily solved?  You can accomplish this with just an enumeration of game states.

Comment: Google "machine learning for tic tac toe" for ideas.

Comment: This idea and code seem familiar.  Did you use [John Dean's Intro to Java](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Programming-Java-Problem-Approach/dp/0073047023) book for this?  Nothing wrong with that, just curious.  That's an excellent book by the way.  It taught me to program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve tic-tac-toe just by enumerating all the game states.  There are a few corners you can cut, but not many.

Here is a nice graphical representation of how to do this.  http://xkcd.com/832/

Comment: I am not seeking for a set of winning states. I am seeking for some kind of an algorithm or something where I can replace the if else

Comment: @Yohan so you're asking us to teach you AI over an SO question and a few answers?  This should be closed as not constructive then.

Comment: Maybe @Yohan is the algorithm and it has gained enough sentience to ask SO for the next move... Skynet is next :P

Comment: +1 For the XKCD reference.  Entertaining AND informative.  That takes some work :-)

Answer (score 1):

I did (almost) this exact thing back in college for an AI class.  The solution I used was to create several functions such as `findBestMove()` and `isGameOver()` etc.  The AI portion was helper functions like `lastSuccessfulMoveForScenario()`.  Tic-Tac-Toe is simple enough that I simply stored in memory every previous move and whether it resulted in a victory.  I then replayed successful moves and pruned away the moves that underperformed.  As the game went on the AI got better and better at playing it.  Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but hopefully it helps.

EDIT:

I should also point out that there are really only a few small cases where the AI has any real decision to make anyway.  It is obvious that you have to block a win, and that you should win if you can.  If I recall only 1 out of 4 moves ended up utilizing the "AI" engine.

Comment: Just be glad you're using Java and not Lisp :-)

Answer (score -1):

For this one, if else is the only way. Eventhough it is a long if else, that is we have to do. check all the winning conditions, and move with if else

Comment: @Yohan as has been suggested to you three times go research AI e.g. google ""machine learning for tic tac toe"

Comment: @djechlin If you want to apply machine learning to this problem... Seriously?

Comment: @ziggystar don't blame me - I posted a non-machine learning solution, OP has insisted in comments and edits.